# Net Core Difference between app.UseMiddleware<T>() and app.Use(context, next)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-middleware

Is there any difference between using IApplicationBuilder of TMiddleware and IApplicationBuilder.Use()? In bot cases I can write elegant extension method and finnaly use

```
app.UseCustomMiddleware()
```

but I don't know the benefits of both approaches.

Answer (score 4):

In the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-3.1),you can find "the `app.Run` delegates don't receive a `next` parameter. The first `Run` delegate is always terminal and terminates the pipeline."

And in the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/write?view=aspnetcore-3.1),app.UseMiddleWare() can receive a next parameter.

`app.UseMiddleWare()`, Middleware is generally encapsulated in a class so that you can reuse the middleware, but for `app.Use()`,you put the code directly in `Configure( IApplicationBuilder )` so you cannot reuse it.

Comment: You can always use app.Use(context, next), that receive next parameter. I asked what's the difference between app.Use and app.UseMiddleware (I edited the post)

Comment: You can also reuse this middleware by defining an extension metod for IApplicationBuilder. Is there any benifint between them?

Comment: In the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/write?view=aspnetcore-3.1),it says `The following extension method exposes the middleware through IApplicationBuilder:`.And in the method,you can see the code `return builder.UseMiddleware<RequestCultureMiddleware>();`.So there is no difference in essence.

Answer (score 0):

`app.UseMiddleware<T>(...)` ends up calling `app.Use(...)`, so `app.Use(...)` is the more primitive of the two mechanisms.

`app.UseMiddleware<T>(...)` enables your middleware to participate in dependency injection, but it's nothing you couldn't do yourself with `app.Use(...)`.